# react-native-element-dropdown returns undefined, onchange not working in the second dropdown

Tags: react-native, dropdown

I have two dropdowns from react native element dropdown, the first one works fine and when i choose the restaurant option i display a second dropdwon, but this one the onChange always returns undefined.

Here is my code

```
export function EcoForm(props) {
  const { formik } = props;
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => {
    setIsEnabled((previousState) => !previousState);
    formik.setFieldValue("eco", isEnabled);
  };
  const dataBusinessType = [
    { label: "Restaurant", value: "restaurant" },
    { label: "Shop", value: "shop" },
    { label: "Acomodation", value: "acomodation" },
  ];
  const dataRestaurantType = [
    { label: "RestaurantTYpe", value: "restaurantType" },
    { label: "Cofee/Bakery", value: "cofee/Bakery" },
  ];

  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [valueRestaurantType, setValueRestaurantType] = useState(null);

  // console.log(isEnabled);
  return (
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Is the business Ecofriendly?</Text>

      <Dropdown
        style={styles.dropdown}
        placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
        selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
        inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
        iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
        data={dataBusinessType}
        search
        maxHeight={300}
        labelField="label"
        valueField="value"
        placeholder="Select business type"
        searchPlaceholder="Search..."
        value={value}
        onChange={(item) => {
          setValue(item.value);
          formik.setFieldValue("businessType", value);
        }}
        renderLeftIcon={() => (
          <AntDesign
            style={styles.icon}
            color="black"
            name="Safety"
            size={20}
          />
        )}
      />
      {value === "restaurant" ? (
        <>

          <Dropdown
            style={styles.dropdown}
            placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
            iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
            data={dataRestaurantType}
            search
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField="label"
            valueField="value"
            placeholder="Select restaurant type"
            searchPlaceholder="Search..."
            value={valueRestaurantType}
            onChange={(item) => {
              setValueRestaurantType(item.valueRestaurantType);
              formik.setFieldValue("restauranType", valueRestaurantType);
              console.log("a ver ", valueRestaurantType);
            }}
            renderLeftIcon={() => (
              <AntDesign
                style={styles.icon}
                color="black"
                name="Safety"
                size={20}
              />
            )}
          /> 

          <CheckBox
            title="Eco friendly"
            checked={isEnabled}
            onPress={() => toggleSwitch()}
          />
          <CheckBox
            title="Vegan"
            checked={isEnabled}
            onPress={() => toggleSwitch()}
          />
        </>
      
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have also tried creating a component with the second dropdown and import it but the behaviour is exactly the same.
Not sure what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the Dropdown Component in react doesn't have any parameter named as Data.

Try to change Data with options like this.

```
      <Dropdown
            style={styles.dropdown}
            placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
            iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
            options={dataRestaurantType}
            search
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField="label"
            valueField="value"
            placeholder="Select restaurant type"
            searchPlaceholder="Search..."
            value={valueRestaurantType}
            onChange={(item) => {
              setValueRestaurantType(item.valueRestaurantType);
              formik.setFieldValue("restauranType", valueRestaurantType);
              console.log("a ver ", valueRestaurantType);
            }}
            renderLeftIcon={() => (
              <AntDesign
                style={styles.icon}
                color="black"
                name="Safety"
                size={20}
              />
            )}
          />
```

Try it out, it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code it's working fine please check the below logs SS:
[image]

```
import React, { memo, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,CheckBox } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
  import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';
  import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';


// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App(props) {
  const { formik } = props;
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => {
    setIsEnabled((previousState) => !previousState);
    formik.setFieldValue("eco", isEnabled);
  };
  const dataBusinessType = [
    { label: "Restaurant", value: "restaurant" },
    { label: "Shop", value: "shop" },
    { label: "Acomodation", value: "acomodation" },
  ];
  const dataRestaurantType = [
    { label: "RestaurantTYpe", value: "restaurantType" },
    { label: "Cofee/Bakery", value: "cofee/Bakery" },
  ];

  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [valueRestaurantType, setValueRestaurantType] = useState(null);

  // console.log(isEnabled);
  return (
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Is the business Ecofriendly?</Text>

      <Dropdown
        style={styles.dropdown}
        placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
        selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
        inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
        iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
        data={dataBusinessType}
        search
        maxHeight={300}
        labelField="label"
        valueField="value"
        placeholder="Select business type"
        searchPlaceholder="Search..."
        value={value}
        onChange={(item) => {
          console.log("item==>",item)
          setValue(item.value);
          formik.setFieldValue("businessType", value);
        }}
        renderLeftIcon={() => (
          <AntDesign
            style={styles.icon}
            color="black"
            name="Safety"
            size={20}
          />
        )}
      />
      {value === "restaurant" ? (
        <>

          <Dropdown
            style={styles.dropdown}
            placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
            selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
            inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
            iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
            data={dataRestaurantType}
            search
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField="label"
            valueField="value"
            placeholder="Select restaurant type"
            searchPlaceholder="Search..."
            value={valueRestaurantType}
            onChange={(item) => {
                            console.log("a ver ", item);
              setValueRestaurantType(item.valueRestaurantType);
              formik.setFieldValue("restauranType", item.valueRestaurantType);
            }}
            renderLeftIcon={() => (
              <AntDesign
                style={styles.icon}
                color="black"
                name="Safety"
                size={20}
              />
            )}
          /> 

          <CheckBox
            title="Eco friendly"
            checked={isEnabled}
            onPress={() => toggleSwitch()}
          />
          <CheckBox
            title="Vegan"
            checked={isEnabled}
            onPress={() => toggleSwitch()}
          />
        </>
      
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
const App=()=>{
retutn( 
<Dropdown
            style={[style.dropdown1, isFocus && { borderColor: 'blue' }]}
            selectedTextStyle={style.selectedTextStyle1}
            data={data}
            maxHeight={300}
            labelField="label"
            valueField="value"
            placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Personal' : ''}
            onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
            onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
            onChange={item => {
              setValue(item.label);
              setIsFocus(false);
            }}
          />
)
}
const styel=styleSheet.create({
 dropdown1: {
    height: 50,
    width: 350,
    marginLeft: 15,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    //borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
  },
 selectedTextStyle1: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
})
```